# Is there a general term for $\zeta((1+2n)/2)/\zeta((1-2n)/2)$

Tags: riemann-zeta

I was looking at this identities in Wikipedia

$$\frac{\zeta(3 / 2)}{\zeta(-1 / 2)}=-4 \pi$$
$$\frac{\zeta(5 / 2)}{\zeta(-3 / 2)}=-\frac{16 \pi^2}{3} $$
$$\frac{\zeta(7 / 2)}{\zeta(-5 / 2)}=\frac{64 \pi^3}{15} $$
$$\frac{\zeta(9 / 2)}{\zeta(-7 / 2)}=\frac{256 \pi^4}{105}$$

And wondering if if there is a general term.

Is there a general term? If there is, what its is and how to obtain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note:*** Errors existed in the previous version of this post. I'm including this notification to illuminate that the errors were fixed.

---

Well, the functional equation immediately tells us that
$$
\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)} = 2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin \left( \frac{\pi s}{2} \right) \Gamma(1-s)
$$
Ultimately, the key to these for $s=\frac{2n+1}{2}$ lies in the value of
$$
\Gamma(1-s) = \Gamma \left( 1-\frac{2n+1}{2} \right)
$$
One might wonder why I chose this expression instead of that of your denominator. The gamma function has a reflection formula (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula)),
$$
\Gamma(s) \Gamma(1-s) = \frac{\pi  }{\sin(\pi s)} \text{ for non-integer } s
$$
So we then have
$$
\Gamma \left( 1-\frac{2n+1}{2} \right)
= \frac{\pi  }{\sin \left( \pi \frac{2n+1}{2}   \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{2n+1}{2} \right)}
$$
This sine term is $(-1)^n$. It is known that
$$
\Gamma \left( \frac{2n+1}{2} \right)
= \Gamma \left( n + \frac 1 2 \right)
= \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n} \sqrt \pi
$$
(see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#Integers_and_half-integers)).

Therefore,
$$
\Gamma \left( 1-\frac{2n+1}{2} \right)
= \frac{(-1)^n \pi }{\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n} \sqrt \pi}
= \frac{(-1)^n 2^n \sqrt \pi }{ (2n-1)!! }
$$
Hence, using the functional equation and simplifying,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\zeta\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)}{\zeta\left(1-\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)} 
&= 2^{\frac{2n+1}{2}} \pi^{\frac{2n+1}{2}-1} \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{2n+1}{2} \right)  \frac{(-1)^n 2^n \sqrt \pi }{ (2n-1)!! } \\
&= 2^{\frac{4n+1}{2}} \pi^{n} \sin \left( \frac{2n+1}{4} \pi \right)  \frac{(-1)^n   }{ (2n-1)!! } \\
\end{align*}$$

One more simplification of sorts can be made: just by looking at what numbers it outputs,
$$
\sin \left(  \frac{2n+1}{4} \pi \right)
= \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} }{\sqrt 2}
$$
so using this we get

$$
\frac{\zeta\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)}{\zeta\left(1-\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)} =  \frac{(-1)^{n+\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} (4\pi)^n  }{ (2n-1)!! }
$$

Not that I can justify this one more than "by playing around", but we can see that
$$
(-1)^{n+\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}
= (-1)^{\lceil n/2 \rceil}
$$
to simplify just a tad more:

$$
\frac{\zeta\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)}{\zeta\left(1-\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)} =  \frac{(-1)^{\lceil n/2 \rceil} (4\pi)^n  }{ (2n-1)!! }
$$

Comment: There is something wrong. Note that for $n=2$ the LHS is $-52.63789013914$ and the RHS is $-131.5947253479$.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, hence the note at the start of the post. I can't seem to track down the error though.

Comment: In the development of $\Gamma\left(1-\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)$ the $2^{n-1}$ should be $2^n$ and the term $2n+1$ where did it come from?

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion myself - that I misremembered the reflection formula and didn't even think to look at it when I cited it. I'll double check the answer I just got and edit accordingly if it works.

Comment: @Neves -- Okay I've found the errors and fixed them. (And as a sanity check, I did indeed check the values listed in the OP/Wikipedia just to be sure and [they match](https://i.imgur.com/JogendE.png).)

Answer (score 4):

If you use the functional equation of the zeta function, it satisfies
$$
\zeta(s)=2^s\pi^{s-1}\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s)
$$
Now observe that if $s=\frac{2n+1}{2}$, then $1-s=1-\frac{2n+1}{2}=\frac{1-2n}{2}$. Thus, the functional equation implies that
$$
\frac{\zeta\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)}{\zeta\left(\frac{1-2n}{2}\right)}=2^{\frac{2n+1}{2}}\pi^{\frac{2n-1}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-2n}{2}\right)
$$

Comment: If it matters at all, thanks to the constraints on the problem / the type of $s$ inputted, one can generate a more specific answer without a dependence on sine or the gamma function (my answer explains this).